# C++ the first cout will not be printed

Tags: c++, cout

As you can see, I have a cout here before the loop starts. Seekg starts at the beginning and the first word in the txtfile is "Hello". But it doesn't print it out(the first cout).

When I remove the while loop, then its not a problem, the first word gets included in the output.

The first "cout", shouldn't it  be printed out no matter what comes after it? How is it possible that next lines of code(THIS case) affects the previous "cout" above it ?

```
 int main()
 {
    string a;
    ifstream myfile;

    myfile.open("test.txt");
    myfile.seekg(0);

    getline(myfile,a);
    cout << a << endl;

    int z = 0;
    while( a != "x" ) {
        myfile.seekg(z);
        getline(myfile,a);
        z += a.size() + 2;
        cout << a << endl;
    }
}
```

I Also should mention that the file starts with "hello", AND contains 600 newlines and a word on every new line. The last line contains "x".

**[EDIT]**

Here's another example. I belive this will be helpful. This is my code now:

```
int main() {

        string a;
        ifstream myfile;
        int newpos = 0;
        myfile.open("example.txt");
        myfile.seekg(newpos);

        getline(myfile,a);


        while (a != "x") {

           myfile.seekg(newpos);

           getline(myfile,a);

           cout << a << endl;

           newpos += a.size() + 2;

        }

}
```

This is my textfile:

```
hello
johan
nils
erik
john
x
```

The output is exactly as it looks in the textfile above.(so far so good).

BUT, then I add about 600 new names to the list/textfile(same structure as above, no changes there, just new names added). Only ONE "hello" at the top so I can track the start, and one x at the end.

This still works with around 100 new names, hello is still printed out in the beginning. But when i add around 600 new names , hello will not be included(the very first cout). Why is that?

Comment: 1. You did not check if the file was successfully opened. 2. First seekg is useless. 3. What compiler? 4. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Prints the first line twice for me.

Comment: @Mat I Also should mention that the file starts with "hello", but contains 600 newlines and a word on every new line. The last line contains "x"

Comment: @ZDF sure sure. But should it really matter if the seekg is useless here, it still starts at 0, and the first "cout" should be printed out nomatter what happens in the loop after it ? Correct me if im wrong

Comment: 1. It should have not effect. 2. As long as you do not state your compiler and you do not post the file, no one can check it.

Comment: If you are debugging, do you see `hello` just aftaer that `cout<<a<<endl;`? You could add some debug statement to see like `cout<<"First line:"<<a<<endl;` to ensure console overflow is not hiding it from the view or something

Comment: Check the encoding of your file. Save it with Western Encoding.

Comment: Can you rewind a stream? You read it then do a seekg. But the first line has already been read so the stream has now moved on and the first char is now the second line. Never used an ifstream but to me this is how a "stream" works.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing variables when you create them. Change `ifstream myfile; myfile.open("test.txt");` to `ifstream myfile("test.txt");`.

Comment: @WilliamJBagshaw -- you can rewind a stream if the stream can be rewound. <g> A stream that's attached to a file can be rewound because a file can be rewound. A stream that's attached to the console can't be rewound because the console can't be rewound. Since this code is reading a file, calls to `seekg` should work fine.

Comment: This, too, doesn't address the question, but the code really should use `tellg()` to get the position after the read. `newpos += a.size() + 2;` uses magic numbers and relies on implementation details. `newpos = myfile.tellg();` works everywhere. But note that the return type of `ifstream::tellg()` (and the correct type for the argument to `seekg`) is `ifstream::pos_type`, so you might get complaints about a type conversion to `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But when I add around 600 new names, hello will not be included (the very first cout).
> **Why is that?**

Looks like your **`Screen Buffer Size`** wasn't big enough to show all of the buffer lines. So when the number of printed lines exceeds a specific height, the console starts to **ignore** the previously printed lines which result you think it didn't print them all.

Since you're using Windows you can try to increase it as so

**For all console apps**

- Right-click the title of the console and choose **Defaults**
- go to **Layout** tab
- Under the Screen Buffer Size, Increase the **`Height`** to (**i.e** **`9001`**)
- Click **OK** then restart the console

**For a specific app**

- Right-click the title of the console and choose **Properties**
- go to **Layout** tab
- Under the Screen Buffer Size, Increase the **`Height`** to (**i.e** **`9001`**)
- Click **OK**.

Note that the Default Height in most Windows Operating systems is **`9001`**.

Comment: **Edit**: Forgot to delete useless `seekg`, you're reading lines, not characters.

Comment: im not getting any errors, and I dont understand why this matters, when the issue here is that the FIRST cout (and maybe some others after it) is being "ignored"? Hello is the first cout, this gets excluded when I add MORE than 100 names to the list. Why would this affect the beginning ? The beginning should be hello nomatter what? What are I missing?

Comment: I meant by error, `run-time error` **not** compiler error that is when you use the first solution in this answer of checking `'x'`, so we had to use `do-while` to prevent that. Can you provide the file you're trying to read? what is being excluded? 1st word? 1st line? Your provided code in this question doesn't have any printing problem, I doubt it's just your compiler. The only problems I saw are the infinite loop in your code and you printed the 1st line twice so I tried to fix all of these in this Answer with the explanation.

Comment: Sorry. Yes, I saw it now but still, what is the problem? Your **edited code** prints each line as it should be with no problem (though still in the infinite loop). Can't you just provide the file-content/output-of-the-console/code-used/compiler-name? that would make it easier to solve, giving more code samples won't solve any of we don't really have much information. Also, try printing an empty line/s at the start of your program and tell me if that worked because it might be a problem with your OS console ignoring the 1st line.

Comment: **"Can't you just provide the file-content/output-of-the-console/" :** Thats what ive done mate in the edited question. The console output looks exactly as the textfile I have in the edited question. (its correct as long as I have those names(or plus 100 more) , but after that, hello gets excluded. You try it! Try it with a txt file with the same content exactly as mine in the example, then add to it(between hello and x)

Comment: I created a text file named `text.txt` and added [these names](https://github.com/dominictarr/random-name/blob/master/first-names.txt) in it with a `hello` in the first line (top of them). I used your  **edited version** of code, and it printed them all with the `hello` to the `x` with no problem. As you can see, that list is about `4945` names with `hello` and `x` = **4947** words been printed successfully.

Comment: I added all your names from the list in to my txtfile, then I run the exactly same code as I have in the edited question. The first name that is printed out is **Tiphanie** and the last name is **Zuzana**, then x. (obviously wrong output, Tiphanie should not be the first name) . Then I remove almost every name and keep only Aaren to Adel, and NOW I get the right output. Aaren is first, Adel is last, then x.

Comment: I understand your problem now! Your console buffer isn't big enough to hold all this buffer, it prints them all but when the buffer exceeds a specific height, the console starts to ignore the previously printed lines which result you think it didn't print them all. Looks like your console screen buffer size height is only about **296-297** lines.

Comment: You're the king! How can increase the buffer? If its not possible how can I notice or keep track of what's being ignored?

Comment: What **OS** are you using?

Comment: If you want to change it for **all** console apps, you can right-click the title of the console and choose `Defaults`, go to Layout tab, under the **Screen Buffer Size**, change `Height` to 9001, click OK. restart the console, if it didn't work for your app, then try to set it from `Properties` when you right-click the title instead of `Defaults`.

Comment: Great stuff man. Appreciate your time. Put up the answer and I will accept

Comment: @QrazyNeo glad to help. :)